# How to make a general function wrapper pickable with pybind11?

Tags: python, c++, pickle, std-function, pybind11

I have a class in c++ containing among other things a `std::function`. Via pybind11 I created a binding for that class, which worked fine. Now I would like to make the class pickleable. However, when trying to pickle an instance of the class in python, I get a `TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects`.

To be precise, here is a minimal example: the c++ class looks like

```
#include<functional>

using Function = std::function<double(double)>;

struct Test {
    Function func;
};
```

The code to generate the python binding reads

```
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "pybind11/functional.h"


namespace py = pybind11;


PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m) {
    py::class_<Test>(m, "Test")
        .def(py::init<Function>())
        .def(py::pickle(
                    [](const Test& t)
                    {
                        return py::make_tuple(t.func);
                    },
                    [](py::tuple tup)
                    {
                        return Test{tup[0].cast<Function>()};
                    }
                    ));
}
```

Now (after the above has been built), if one tries to pickle an instance of the class in python

```
import pickle

from my_module import Test


def identity(entity):
    return entity


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = Test(identity)
    with open('test.pickle', 'wb') as out_file:
        pickle.dump(test, out_file)
```

one gets the error mentioned above:

```
TypeError: can't pickle PyCapsule objects
```

which is raised by the line `pickle.dump(test, out_file)`.

Is there any way to make pickling work without loosing generality? That is, I would really like to be able to invoke the class with an arbitrary python callable with signature `float -> float`.

One gets the same error if `func` is wrapped into a `py::cpp_function`, that is, if one replaces `return py::make_tuple(t.func)` with `return py::make_tuple(py::cpp_function{t.func})`.

Comment: If you knew your callable was going to be from some fixed set you could index them somehow, but this is going to be difficult for arbitrary functions. If they are pure python functions then you might be able to use the `dill` module, which you might also be able to extend for wrapped C++ functions

Comment: Thanks @ChrisD for the suggestions! Indeed I am aiming at both pure python functions and wrapped C++ functions. After doing a very superficial research, I am not under the impression that there is any obvious way to implement this using `dill`. Anyhow, for the application I have in mind I can circumvent the problem without the need to pickle a general callable (by sacrificing some elegance, but better sacrifice elegance instead of needed functionality).